# Android how to set max limit on results for program that calculates sum of numbers?

Tags: java, android

I've written a program that calculates the sum of 4 inputed values which are typed in by the user.

I want to limit the result to a maximum value of 6 (with any result >6 returning a value of "6").

For example if the sum of the 4 numbers is 10 then it will automatically be changed to 6.

The java code is:

```
EditText editText3;
EditText editText4;
EditText editText6;
EditText editText8;
TextView textViewResult;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    editText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    editText4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    editText6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    editText8.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

private String addNumbers() {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    int number4;
    if(editText3.getText().toString() != "" && editText3.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if(editText4.getText().toString() != "" && editText4.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }
    if(editText6.getText().toString() != "" && editText6.getText().length() > 0) {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(editText6.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number3 = 0;
    }
    if(editText8.getText().toString() != "" && editText8.getText().length() > 0) {
        number4 = Integer.parseInt(editText8.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number4 = 0;
    }

    return Integer.toString((number1*2) + (number2*4) + (number3*2) + (number4*2));

}
}
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're question is only about the sum of integers. This has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: You can do something like if(sum)>=6 assign value 6 to your result field

Comment: Two suggestions:
1: Use a single instance of `TextWatcher()` and pass it into each `addTextChangeListener()` call.
2: Use a function to handle the logic to get a number from the `EditText` object. E.g. `int getNumberForInput(EditText input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change: "`return Integer.toString((number1*2) + (number2*4) + (number3*2) + (number4*2));`" to this:

```
int sum = (number1*2) + (number2*4) + (number3*2) + (number4*2);
if(sum>6) sum = 6;
return sum+"";
```